# power automate to make classic SharePoint site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

i a trying to use power auotmate to make a classic sharepoint site, i keep getting errors but only when i run th sts#0 template any advice?

````
  "request": { 
    "Title": "@{triggerOutputs()?['body/Title']}",
    "Url":"@{triggerOutputs()?['body/NewURL']}",
    "Lcid": 1033,
    "ShareByEmailEnabled":false,
    "Description":"@{triggerOutputs()?['body/Justification']}",
    "WebTemplate":"sts#0",
    "Owner":"SharePoint Service Administrator",
"TimeZoneId":"@{variables('VarTimeZone')}"
  }
}```
````

Comment: Could you please provide the errors you have been receiving?

Comment: my uri is _api/SPSiteManager/create
 i am getting a this error 
"status": 400,
  "message": "siteTemplate\r\nParameter name: Performing this operation on a site with this template is not allowed.\r\nclientRequestId: 4e66ddfc-4909-4afc-8113-cd7dfc33c9e4\r\nserviceRequestId: dda050a0-00b2-0000-1325-381ffb727328",

Comment: The owner "SharePoint Service Administrator", is this an actual account on your tenant? SharePoint will be expecting an actual user account.

Comment: I am able to run this with all modern sharepoint site creations sts#3, Stagepublishing#0, I am trying to get this to work with  sts#0 (classic sharepoint teams site)

Comment: I've provided an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation suggests that this endpoint (/_api/SPSiteManager/create) can be used for modern sites but does not at any point state that it can be used for classic site collection templates.

[Manage modern SharePoint sites using REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/apis/site-creation-rest)

Your error message also suggests that classic site templates are not supported by the endpoint.

Comment: is there a way to make a classic site collection?

Comment: I've not seen any way to create a classic site collection via the REST API, the best I know of is this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints#creating-a-site-with-rest which seems to allow you to create classic subsites. I'm fairly sure it can be done via CSOM though.

Comment: If my answer has helped in any way, please do upvote or mark the answer as accepted to help inform the community.